# Module 'base' has no dex files but the attribute 'hasCode' is not set to false in the AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, android-app-bundle

Android app bundle tool is throwing the error mentioned above.

Here is my app level gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'dexguard'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'


android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.compileSdk
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'


    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    bundle {
        language {
            // Specifies that the app bundle should not support
            // configuration APKs for language resources. These
            // resources are instead packaged with each base and
            // dynamic feature APK.
            enableSplit = false
        }
        density {
            // This property is set to true by default.
            enableSplit = true
        }
        abi {
            // This property is set to true by default.
            enableSplit = true
        }
    }


    defaultConfig {

        applicationId "com.xxxxx.xxxxx"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.minSdk
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.compileSdk
        versionCode rootProject.versionCode
        versionName rootProject.versionName
        resConfigs "en", "hi", "ta"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true

        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                arguments = ["room.schemaLocation": "$projectDir/schemas".toString()]
            }
        }
        return true
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {

            proguardFile getDefaultDexGuardFile('dexguard-debug.pro')
            proguardFile 'dexguard-project.txt'

            return true
        }
        release {

            proguardFile getDefaultDexGuardFile('dexguard-release.pro')
            proguardFile 'dexguard-project.txt'

            return true
        }
    }


    return true

}

dependencies {
    // playServices
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:17.0.0"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-config:16.1.0"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:16.0.2"
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.5'

    // supportLibrary
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$supportLibraryVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$supportLibraryVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:design:$supportLibraryVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$supportLibraryVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:customtabs:$supportLibraryVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-media-compat:$supportLibraryVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:$supportLibraryVersion"
    implementation 'com.google.android.instantapps:instantapps:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher:0.8.5'

    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

    // Third party
   // Others are here

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Does building an APK work and run as expected on a device? It looks like your project doesn't produce a dex file. Also, what version of Gradle and Studio are you using?

Comment: Hi pierre, Thanks for your time, Actually issue was with dexguard version. its fixed now

Comment: Great news, thanks for letting me know! Consider suggesting a solution and accepting it to show your problem has been resolved (and in case someone encounters the same problem).

Comment: @Pierre how did you fix the issue ?

Answer (score 2):

Found the issue :

If this happening only in the release build then it is possibly proguard issue .
Proguard removes the files from the dynamic module if it considers them not useful.
So , you have to modify the proguard keep rules .

**In proguard file 
-keep class whateverpackagename.** { *; }**

P.S. also check if multidex feature is enabled or not .

Comment: @PayelDutta
replace whateverpackagename with your folder package name 
like if the folder name is abc then com.example.abc
 -keep class whateverpackagename. { *; }**

Answer (score 0):

I had this error and it disappeared when I downgraded Android Gradle Plugin Version and Gradle Version in Project Structure window to 3.5.4 and 5.6.4